# Help with XSLT to transform XML: grouping and selecting elements with max value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the current XML:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2315</CustomerId>
    <Date>2011-04-28 14:14:00</Date>   
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2316</CustomerId>
    <Date>2011-04-28 15:03:00</Date>
    <VersionNumber>2</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2317</CustomerId>
    <Date>2011-04-28 15:03:00</Date>
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>9995DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
</DocumentElement>
```

What I am trying to do is to filter out one element of each GUID with the highest version number, i.e, transform the document above to look like:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2316</CustomerId>
    <Date>2011-04-28 15:03:00</Date>
    <VersionNumber>2</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>2E05DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerId>2317</CustomerId>
    <Date>2011-04-28 15:03:00</Date>
    <VersionNumber>1</VersionNumber>
    <GUID>9995DE20-02A0-425D-944D-65E5E744FF8A</GUID>
  </Customer>
</DocumentElement>
```

Anyone who can point me in the right direction on where to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an exercise, I've tried to solve this using XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

  <xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Customer" group-by="GUID">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()
                          [VersionNumber=max(current-group()/VersionNumber)]" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Major differences:

- with XSLT 2.0 you don't need to define an `xsl:key` as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813962/help-with-xslt-to-transform-xml/5815805#5815805), but you can use `xsl:for-each-group ... group-by="GUID"`
- with XPath 2.0 you have the `fn:max(...)` function

Comment: +1: I was already hoping someone would provide this, as I am not yet accustomed to XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0; thanks!

Comment: @MarcoS: It is not necessary to define the F&O namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` and it is not necessary to prefix standard XPath function names. Please, simplify your code.

Comment: @MarcoS: You are welcome. I reformatted your code for achieving better readability.

Comment: @Dimitre: thanks! I just re-edited it, because you had misplaced the `>` in `<xsl:stylesheet ...` :)

Comment: +1 Correct XSLT 2.0 answer. I would take the maximum calculation out because I don't trust much in processors' optimization...

Comment: @Alejandro: what do you mean exactly by "taking the maximum calculation out"?

Comment: @MarcoS: `<xsl:variable name="vMax" select="max(current-group()/VersionNumber)"/> <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[VersionNumber=$vMax]"/>`

Comment: Nice (and educational) to have both versions side by side :]

Answer (score 1):

I would start with declaring a [key](http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/resources/xslkeys/index.htm) on GUID, this enables to easily process distinct GUIDs; then, per GUID, sort the corresponding Customer elements on their VersionNumber and simply copy the first (xslt-1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byGUID" match="Customer" use="GUID"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- process first Customer for each distinct GUID -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Customer[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byGUID',GUID))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- sort and process all Customers with the same GUID -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byGUID',GUID)" mode="copyFirst">
            <xsl:sort select="VersionNumber" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copyFirst">
        <!-- only copy the first (highest VersionNumber) -->
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this intersection of nodesets is another way to process the first Customer for each distinct GUID:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Customer[count(.|key('byGUID',GUID)[1])=1]"/>
```

Comment: To avoid incremental matches, you could use `<xsl:template match="/">`, `<xsl:template match="Customer">` and `<xsl:template match="Customer" mode="copyFirst">`

Comment: @rekaszeru: thanks, though matching `/` will not work with `copy` then…

Comment: picking up the previous comment from rekaszeru, you could use `<xsl:template match="DocumentElement">`, `<xsl:template match="Customer">`, and `<xsl:template match="Customer" mode="copyFirst">`